# Orbit around a gameobject in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

In Unity I have a camera with the following structure

```
GameObject Pan
    => GameObject Rotation
       => GameObject Zoom
          => GameObject Camera (the component that have the camera script)
```

I have an object target

```
GameObject target;
```

I want to rotate in all the direction around that object. Like if it's a flying plane, so I can rotate up down left right.

I have the following code

```
void ChangePosition()
{
    if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") != 0 || Input.GetAxis("Vertical") != 0)
    {
        if (target)
        {
            transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, transform.right, -Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed);
            transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, transform.up, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed);

            rotationObject.transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);
        }
    }
}
```

It works great when you move only Left, or only up.

But if you move booth in the same time, the rotation is not intuitive anymore. It also rotate the camera on herself.

I would like the camera to only move left or up (so rotate around on 2 axis but never on herself)

How can I fix it ?

Comment: how do you mean its  not intuative..

Comment: If you try the code you will understand, It will instead of moving in diagonal, it will Roll on herself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not like to use `RotateAround()` but their is a much simpler solution. First modify your hierarchy, add a new object that is your rotation center a place it at the center of your Target object.

```
GameObject Target (your target game object)
    => GameObject RotationCenter (local position: 0, 0, 0. The center of Target)
         => GameObject Camera
```

Then simply rotate you new gameobject `RotationCenter`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
RotationCenter.Rotate(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed);
```

Comment: Actually I found out that 

changing the second line to transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed); did the trick. Thank you for you answer, I will try it also

Comment: @Bobby Ok cool :) But be careful with `RotateAround` and `LookAt` if your object is moving sometimes it can have weird behavior