# Rotating camera around sphere in Unity/C# using arrow keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently learning Unity and have been stuck for a while on a project I am doing.

I have a Mars model that is given torque to rotate and has two moons orbiting it. I want to be able to move the camera around it using the arrow keys but I cant seem to figure it out.

Current code (all in a single script called GameManager):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject mars;//planet
    public GameObject phobos;//moon1
    public GameObject deimos;//moon2
    public GameObject refpoint;//empty game object I placed inside mars
    //All object are referenced using the inspector

    void Start()
    {
        Camera.main.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,-200);

        Camera.main.transform.LookAt(mars.transform.position);

        Rigidbody rb = mars.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(0,20,0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if(Input.GetKey("up")){
            Camera.main.transform.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position, Vector3.right, 50* Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey("down")){
            Camera.main.transform.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position, Vector3.right, -50* Time.deltaTime);
        }else if(Input.GetKey("right")){
            Camera.main.transform.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position, Vector3.up, -50* Time.deltaTime);
        }else if(Input.GetKey("left")){
            Camera.main.transform.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position, Vector3.up, 50* Time.deltaTime);
        }

        phobos.transform.RotateAround(mars.transform.position, phobos.transform.up, 60*Time.deltaTime);
        deimos.transform.RotateAround(mars.transform.position, deimos.transform.up, 50*Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

Initially this works fine, but the directions start getting confused once you use left/right after up/down or vice versa.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Orbit around a gameobject in unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57975282/orbit-around-a-gameobject-in-unity)

Comment: @BugFinder not really.

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but shouldn't `Camera.main.transform.transform.RotateAround` be `Camera.main.transform.RotateAround`

Comment: @Flexicoder still gives the same issue after removing the extra transform

Comment: @MohamadMoustafa did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

I believe RotateAround here is a mistake. With the other suggested solutions you would rapidly get lost in the rotation, with the camera ending up upside down or even sideways.

```
public class GameManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject mars;//planet
    public GameObject phobos;//moon1
    public GameObject deimos;//moon2
    public GameObject refpoint;//empty game object I placed inside mars
    //All object are referenced using the inspector

    public float cameraAngularVelocity = 60f;
    public float cameraDistance = 200;
    public float cameraAngleY = 0;
    public float cameraAngleX = 0;

    private Camera mainCam;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float angleDelta = cameraAngularVelocity * Time.deltaTime;

        //Standard Input management
        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            cameraAngleX += angleDelta;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            cameraAngleX -= angleDelta;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            cameraAngleY -= angleDelta;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            cameraAngleY += angleDelta;
        }
        //Alternative using axis
        cameraAngleX += Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * angleDelta;
        cameraAngleY += Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * angleDelta;

        //Protections
        cameraAngleX = Mathf.Clamp(cameraAngleX, -90f, 90f);
        cameraAngleY = Mathf.Repeat(cameraAngleY, 360f);

        Quaternion cameraRotation =
            Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraAngleY, Vector3.up)
            * Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraAngleX, Vector3.right);

        Vector3 cameraPosition =
            refpoint.transform.position
            + cameraRotation * Vector3.back * cameraDistance;

        mainCam.transform.position = cameraPosition;
        mainCam.transform.rotation = cameraRotation;

        phobos.transform.RotateAround(mars.transform.position, phobos.transform.up, 60 * Time.deltaTime);
        deimos.transform.RotateAround(mars.transform.position, deimos.transform.up, 50 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This solution locks your roll, and prevents you passing the vertical through the X rotation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would be better if you defined another function for getting a new Vector for the rotation, like this:

```
Vector3 CalculateRotationVector(){
    Vector3 RotationVector = Vector3.zero;

    if(Input.GetKey("up")){
        RotationVector += Vector3.right;
    }
    else if(Input.GetKey("down")){
        RotationVector -= Vector3.right;
    }else if(Input.GetKey("right")){
        RotationVector -= Vector3.right;
    }else if(Input.GetKey("left")){
        RotationVector += Vector3.right;
    }

    return RotationVector;

}
```

And in your update function you may call it like this:

```
void Update(){
    Camera.main.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position, CalculateRotationVector(), 50* Time.deltaTime);
}
```

However I'm not really sure if this will work since I can't try this on unity right now, might give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You don't always want to rotate around the global right axis. You can use a cross product between global `down` and the direction from the reference point to the camera to find a suitable axis.

This logic requires that you prevent the camera from going directly above or below the planet. Clamp the vertical rotation based on the angle between global up/down and the direction from the reference to the camera and some "minimum angle" the camera can be from the up/down axis.

Also, `Camera.main` calls `FindGameObjectsWithTag` internally, so it is [recommended](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) to cache the results.

Altogether, this might look like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManagerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public GameObject mars;//planet
    public GameObject phobos;//moon1
    public GameObject deimos;//moon2
    public GameObject refpoint;//empty game object I placed inside mars
    //All object are referenced using the inspector

    private Camera mainCam;
    private float cameraRotateSpeed = 50f;
    private float cameraMinVerticalAngle = 10f;

    void Start()
    {
        mainCam = Camera.main;

        mainCam.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,-200);

        mainCam.transform.LookAt(mars.transform.position);

        Rigidbody rb = mars.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(0,20,0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float horizontalRotateDirection = 0f;
        float verticalRotateDirection = 0f;


        if(Input.GetKey("up")){
            doRotate = true;
            verticalRotateDirection += 1f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("down")){
            doRotate = true;
            verticalRotateDirection -= 1f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("right")){
            doRotate = true;
            horizontalRotateDirection += 1f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey("left")){
            doRotate = true;
            verticalRotateDirection -= 1f;
        }

        float horizontalRotateAmount = horizontalRotateDirection 
                * cameraRotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        float verticalRotateAmount = verticalRotateDirection 
                * cameraRotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Prevent camera from flipping
        Vector3 fromRefToCam = (mainCam.transform.position - refpoint.transform.position).normalized;

        float maxRotateDown = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.down, fromRefToCam);
        float maxRotateUp = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, fromRefToCam)

        verticalRotateAmount = Mathf.Clamp(verticalRotateAmount, 
                cameraMinVerticalAngle - maxRotateDown, 
                maxRotateUp - cameraMinVerticalAngle);

        Vector3 verticalRotateAxis = Vector3.Cross(Vector3.down, fromRefToCam); 

        //Rotate horizontally around global down
        mainCam.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position, 
                    Vector3.up, 
                    horizontalRotateAmount);

        // Rotate vertically around camera's right (in global space)
        mainCam.transform.RotateAround(refpoint.transform.position,
                    verticalRotateAxis, 
                    verticalRotateAmount);


        phobos.transform.RotateAround(mars.transform.position, phobos.transform.up, 
                60*Time.deltaTime);
        deimos.transform.RotateAround(mars.transform.position, deimos.transform.up, 
                50*Time.deltaTime);

    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at this.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

With this you can rotate around a given point. If you combine this with key input and a constant speed multiplied by `Time.deltaTime` this might work

Comment: While the link may answer the question now, the usefulness of this question depends greatly on how long the link remains valid. If you were to take information needed at the link to answer the question and include that in the answer itself, that would greatly improve the long term quality of the answer.

Comment: this is a link to the official unity api, this is always valid... so i dont get your downvote at all. I post this here cause they have code examples, an this is the first place you should check if looking for inspiration...

Comment: I didn't downvote it before but looking again, this answer describes what is already in the question.  It does nothing to explain why it might not be working for the asker or how to even begin fixing the problem.